# Vertical align not working button

Tags: html, css

I have html that looks like:

```
<header>
   <div class='content'>
      <div class='pull-left'>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      </div>

      <div class='pull-right'>
        <a href='#'>
          <button class='edit'>Edit Book</button>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The h1 will always be there, but the h2 is optional (so the height is dynamic). What I'm trying to do is vertically center the Edit Book button so it is in the middle of .content. I've tried `vertical-align:center` on the button, but it doesn't work

EDIT: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v8SfN/

Comment: Can you show more of your CSS? `vertical-align` won't do it. You need `position`

Comment: it's [`vertical-align:middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align), not `center`.

Comment: @putvande, I made a JSfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go down a sightly different route instead of using bootstrap's inbuilt classes:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4892/)

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class='layout-valign'>
        <div>
             <h1>Hello World</h1>    
             <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>    
        </div>
        <div> <a href='#'>
          <button class='edit'>Edit Book</button>
        </a>    
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.layout-valign {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.layout-valign>div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.layout-valign>div:last-child {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using Bootstrap? But the answer is great! Thanks

Comment: @the_ - apologies it was an assumption based on the class names you have, in that case the above should work anyhow :)